# Is it possible to use knative with Kustomize - kubectl apply -k knative.yaml

Tags: kustomize

I am looking for a workflow with knative.

Is it possible to use knative file with kustomize?

Comment: Yes, you can use kustomize to override any Kubernetes manifest file

Comment: Ok, but how do Kustomize know what to do regarding Knative CRDs. Is there some kind of templating?

Comment: With kustomize you override a base manifest, instead of templating and you can use it on all kind of Kubernetes manifests.

Comment: For anything other than k8s build-in types, if you need to provide merge key and patch strategy information about custom resource types, you will have to provide your own OpenAPI schema to do so.